# Making a Trial version of a program

Tags: vb.net

I am making trial version of my `vb .net` project but it is not counting the days , date and time .

Can u please give me any suggestions to correct it. I am using the following code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim intTime As Integer = 1
    Dim dteLastStart, dteStartDate As Date
    Dim blnFirstTime, blnEnabled As Boolean
    Dim lngTimeLeft As Long

    blnEnabled = True
    If dteStartDate = Nothing Then
        dteStartDate = Now
    End If

    My.Application.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True


    If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dteLastStart, Now) < 0 Then
        'First clock change
        If intTime = 1 Then
            MsgBox("FRED has detected that you have changed your system date to an earlier date" & vbCrLf & "As FRED has built-in security," & vbCrLf & "FRED will only run until the next intTime you change your system date", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "System Date Changed")
            intTime = 2
        ElseIf intTime = 2 Then
            'Second clock change
            blnEnabled = False
            MsgBox("FRED has detected that you have changed your system date to an earlier date" & vbCrLf & "As this is the second warning, FRED will now be disabled", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "System Date Changed")
        End If
        'disables app
        If blnEnabled = False Then
            If MsgBox("FRED is disabled", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Disabled") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                For Each form As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
                    form.Close()
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dteStartDate, Now) > 29 Then
        blnEnabled = False
        If blnEnabled = False Then
            If MsgBox("FRED has reached the end of it's trial.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Trial Ended") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                'Close all open forms
                For Each form As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
                    form.Close()
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
    dteLastStart = Now
    If blnFirstTime = True Then
        blnFirstTime = False
    End If
    'Saves variable settings
    My.Settings.Save()

    lngTimeLeft = 29 - (DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dteStartDate, Now))

    MsgBox("This is a 29-day trial version." & vbCrLf & "You have " & CStr(lngTimeLeft) & " days left.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "FRED Trial")
end sub
end class
```

Comment: well, i don't see where dteLastStart is receiving value from. What i suggest to do, is on first run, save a value of datetime in registry in some encoded way. Then on each run pull that value and compare to now.

Comment: can u plz tell me how to save a value of date time in registry

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your program called "MyProg" and you want user to try it for 7 days.

So, conceptually, you'll have entry in registry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyProg
```

Each run of the software, you will have to check if it exists, if not, assuming it's a first run and you will create the entry and set value. If entry exists, you will retrieve value and compare to now.

No for coding, here is an example function that handles registry and returns false if date expired or true if still trial period:

```
Private Function HandleRegistry() As Boolean
        Dim firstRunDate As Date
        firstRunDate = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProg", "FirstRun", Nothing)
        If firstRunDate = Nothing Then
            firstRunDate = Now
            My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyProg", "FirstRun", firstRunDate)
        ElseIf (Now - firstRunDate).Days > 7 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End Function
```

No all you have to do, is to call it and handle response:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim result As Boolean = HandleRegistry()
        If result = False Then 'something went wrong
            MsgBox("Trial expired")
        Else
            MsgBox("Trial version")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Of course this is example only, so you get the idea, but practicality i would encode date and call registry name entry something else so it won't be user friendly. Also, remember the architecture issue so you know where it's written.

Hope that helps

Comment: i would like to ask one more thing from u plz

Comment: if i put both of these codes which u have told me as an answer . Will my program be a trial which will expire after 7 days exactly?

Comment: well, actually by given code yes. but you can manipulate it by changing this condition: ElseIf (Now - firstRunDate).Days > 7 Then

Comment: i have to ask One thing more plz

Comment: there is a website which has 4 web pages . on first page there is a button, on 2nd page there are also some buttons, on 3rd page there is also a single button , on 4th page also contained a single button. Problem is that my code programatically clicks the button of first page 2nd page and 3rd page  . But is is not clicking the button on 4th page programatically. How can i enable my code to do that??? Please suggest a reliable solution for this .. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the question... click on button pragmatically on 4th page?..

Comment: yes i have used the same coding which i am using on the previous page