# How should I go about to create a demo of my software with limited functionality?

Tags: vb.net, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a demo of my software with limited functionality. What is a good way of doing this?

More details about my specific situation:
I am developing small scale software and don't worry about crackers and such, but still I want to get the best protection for my software with the least effort. The application I am developing is written in VB.NET and I am writing it in Visual Studio 2013.

There are many questions marks I have about this:
-Does this kind of protection take time to implement or is there a simple way? (I'm looking for a simple implementation)
-Should I use some kind of third-party service for this?
-If I use license keys, how do I generate the license keys?

I would be glad for either a complete or partial answer to my question

Comment: Personally I would go for a full version which starts off as a trial, then can be converted to a full version via a serial key. There will always be some people who want the full version for free and try to find their way around it; personally I've found that the best solution to tackle this is to make your application so awesome they do not want to pirate it.

Comment: I agree.. create a full version with two user modes demo/full. On installation the demo mode is default until a licence key is entered and validated. The functions you want to limit will then check which mode the app is running it. I tend to have a time limited demo mode.

Answer (score 2):

A basic solution is
1. Using registry (Windows) 2. or a license file. 3. or Online activation

I just give you the technical suggestion not code.

1. Using registry
   Complete your soft but on the init page (Starting page) do the registry checking and find for a key if it is available load your project with full access, if not load with limited features.
2. Using license file
   When client install your software to their machine. Your software first ask the product key. If a valid product key entered your software can generate a machine specific license file and store it to your  software's installation location. From the next time your soft will get the license file while opening so it will not ask for a product key.

   Now for machine specific license you can use device MAC (But it is a bad practice), Client name and details information and the encrypt it and save as license file.
3. Using online activation
   You can easily create online activation. In this case when some one buy your soft you just create a online account for him to your activation system and give the client the product key generated by your online activation system. So than when client enter product key your soft can download client info and store it as a license file.

There are many other techniques available. And you can implement your one also. Think!

Comment: Do you have a link to a simple implementation of these protection techniques that I get copy/derive from? If I start from scratch I believe my protection will be very flawed. A reputable guide would be much appreciated. Like usually there are a few products that a best in a certain niche. I envision that hopefully there is one or a few guides that I can follow to get protection into my software.

Comment: Start with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184289/making-a-trial-version-of-a-program